# EC2 Nginx Reverse Proxy Angular S3 Bucket getting 404 Not Found error

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy

I have an EC2 Instance with Nginx as the web server. I have an Angular 7 SPA sitting in an S3 bucket, that has been properly set up to serve web content. I have Nginx reverse proxy set up so that request to '/' will be served up by the staic SPA in the S3 bucket. After a bit of configuring the Nginx reverse proxy I was able to get the SPA served up and appears to be working properly.

The Problem

In Chrome when watching the network tab in DevTools the network request is showing as "404 Not Found" same in Firefox.
So the app appears to be loading and working but I think that I need to do something to address the fact the request comes back as 404 Not Found.

Eventually this will be a Angular SPA served up from the S3 bucket with an /api that Nginx will also reverse proxy to a Node Express app running on the EC2 instance.

The file that I can think that would be relevant to this discussion would be my Nginx default.conf, which is shown here.

```
server {
    server_name  idlewildeave.com;

    location / {
    #    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #    index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_http_version     1.1;
        proxy_set_header       Connection '';
        proxy_set_header       Host ng4app.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com;
        proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
        proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
        proxy_ignore_headers   'Set-Cookie';
        proxy_buffering        off;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_redirect         off;
        proxy_pass             http://ng4app.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/xxxx/xxxx.com/xxxx; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/xxxx/xxxx.com/xxxxx; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/xxxx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/xxxx.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = idlewildeave.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen       80;
    server_name  idlewildeave.com;
    # return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: If you look at the response headers, `x-amz-error-detail-Key: index.html.` suggests that a file is missing. But as the 404 page loads up your JS, the app appears to render something reasonable.

Comment: Looking through the response headers this was the response for the one suggested, "x-amz-error-detail-Key: index.html.". The problem was the period at the end. In the S3 console when setting this bucket up for "Static Website hosting" the index document was incorrect with "index.html." that "." at the end was the problem, remove "." and 404 error disappears.

Comment: Hi @JamesMcCauley- I have the same issue. But where are you looking to find "x-amz-error-detail-Key: index.html.".?